# AppCompactActivity handle data after orientation android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

I need to handle some data when orientation is changed in my AppCompatActivity. For some reason my set

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putInt("mode", REDEEM);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    MODE = savedInstanceState.getInt("mode");
}
```

I have tried this and it doesn't work.

Most likely because I have this below in my manifest.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

How can I fix this without changing my manifest?`

Comment: Did you tested by putting app in background, in place of change orientation ?

Comment: How do you mean? I want to allow orientation change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you declare `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`, the pair `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` are not called. The reason is that the activity is not destroyed and recreated as normally happens, so you don't have states to save/restore. In this case you have to override the `onConfigurationChanged` callback, but the value of `MODE` should be preserved anyway. Please be aware the handling the orientation change is **strongly discouraged**

Comment: So it would be better to let the activity be destroyed?

Comment: Yes it is strongly recommend